# Can you tell me what is the keyerror in this picture?

Tags: python, django, keyerror

I don't know what is the problem to run `Django`.

[image]

Comment: you need pass a ```HE_CLIENT_SECRET``` parameter.

Comment: Please add the traceback as text, not as an image. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe adding a tag with your operating system would help? Also, it's better to paste the text than to take a screenshot.

Comment: How can i add a key with my os? Thank u !

Answer (score 0):

Django is looking for your HackerEarth API Key in your environment variables and not finding it. Either set `HE_CLIENT_SECRET` to this key before starting your Django server or consult the documentation for whatever you're trying to run to see if you can set it in `settings.py` for your project.

Comment: Thank u for your answer!!
Yes i made a secret key and inserted key. But i have a still problem it occured 400 error..

I entered the key instead of HE_CLIENT_SECRET directly. Is that a problem? Thx!

Comment: You should set the value of the variable `HE_CLIENT_SECRET` in `settings.py` to the key that you obtained (or do the same with an environment variable with the same name. If you're now getting a different error, is they key correct? There may be some other problem with the configuration of your Django project, in which case you'll need to ask another question.